# Did I really join the table successfully in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Following a tutorial, I learn to join the vector layer "tl_2013_06_tract" with text layer "ca_tracts_pop" which contains population information. Because the identifier variable in ca_tracts_pop is text, I create a csvt file simultaneously to interpret the format. After that, the population attribute seems to be attached to vector layer successful (it appear in the new attribute table).

[image]

However, when I try to style the vector in the latter step, I can only find two original variables of  tl_2013_06_tract in the pull-down menu  in the Graduated tab.

[image]

And when opening the database manager, I could not find the new population attribute. So I wonder if I join the table successfully at the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply the graduated style because it only accept numerical fields. Hence, you have two ways to perform your task.

The first one is the fastest: as reported by @ndawson in the comments, you just need to click the "E" expression button next to the field choice in the graduated renderer and directly enter the espression: `to_int("ca_tracts_pop_DOC")`.

Otherwise, you may create a new field in your joined "tl_2013_06_tract" layer. For doing this, try the following steps:

1. Firstly, open the Attribute Table of the joined "tl_2013_06_tract" layer;
2. Open the field calculator:

[image]

3. Create a new numerical (integer in this case) field using the expression in the image below (`"ca_tracts_pop_DOC"` is the name of your field containing strings)

[image]

4. Click the OK button;
5. Save Edits;
6. Untoggle Editing Mode.

Now you should be able to apply the categorized style to your joined layer.

Comment: You don't actually need to create a new field to do this - just click the "E" expression button next to the field choice in the graduated renderer and enter the `to_int("ca_tracts_pop_DOC")` expression directly. No need to modify the layer itself!

Comment: I didn't know it was possible, thanks @ndawson for the hint! I'll update the answer to make it clearer =)

Comment: Thank you, @HowToInQGIS and @ndawson for your kind and helpful guide and discussion. I have tested both solutions and find only the second approach (create new field) works, this may due to my OGIS setting or the data, I don't know. What's funny is, after joining, the original attribute name changed from `ca_tracts_pop_DOC` to `ca_tracts_pop_DOO1` in the `field and values` tab. I don't know if it's normal.

Comment: All the field must have different names: if it happens the contrary, QGIS will automatically rename them by truncating them and by inserting a numerical value.